# the incorporation or incorporating

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

How I could say that my paragraph discusses something in a correct English sentence.

> This paragraph discusses the incorporating method A in the B context.

or

> This paragraph discusses the incorporation of method A in the B context.

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence almost sounds right, but not quite.

I would make it:

> This paragraph discusses the incorporation of method A in context B.

---

Alternatively, depending on the exact situation, it could be one of the following:

> This paragraph discusses the incorporation of method A in the context of B.
>   This paragraph discusses the incorporation of method A using context B.

But the important thing is that since you use *method* before *A*, you should maintain consistency and also use *context* before *B*.